# Free Database Browser for PostgreSQL?

Tags: windows-7, database, sql, postgresql

Does anyone know of a free PostgreSQLdatabase browser that I can use besides [RazorSQL](http://www.razorsql.com/download.html) since It has a 30 day trial? It would be great to have something similar to the SQlite Database Browser, light weight and easy to read. It doesn't have to just use PostgreSQL, it can be any browser that can use PostgreSQL as well.

Comment: See also [Community Guide to PostgreSQL GUI Tools](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- [pgAdmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/) -> Only for PostgreSQL
- [SQL Workbench](http://www.sql-workbench.net/) -> For many RDBMS

Comment: For PostgreSQL-only browser I also recommend [pgAdmin](http://www.pgadmin.org).

Answer (score 3):

The general purpose sql-db browser from [sqlmaestro](http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/anysql/) is also quite good.